# How to know the chromium path used by puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian, puppeteer

I installed puppeteer on my debian server, and I'm trying to use it through php :

```
print shell_exec("node pptscript.js");
```

pptscript.js:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: '/var/www/web/example.png'});    
  await browser.close();
})();
```

But it doesn't work and I have no output.

I read somewhere that chmoding to 777 the chromium executable can solve the problem because user www-data have no right to execute it. But I don't know where is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser` has an internal function called `process()` which returns a [ChildProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You can read the `spawnfile` property of that `ChildProcess`.

```js
console.log(browser.process().spawnfile);
```